# Udinic AccountAuthenticator migrate to Android Studio

Tags: android, authentication, android-studio, intellij-idea, migration

How do I migrate this:

> https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator

to Android Studio?

I am not proud to admit I am having trouble migrating Udini's very fine example to Android Studio. It's originally an IntelliJ project from 2013.

http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

I thought I had it finally imported from github but I still can't get it to run. When I try to run ExampleApp/Main1 
the Edit Configuration screen pops up and states: !Error: Module not specified

[image]

I always run the latest Android Studio (as of today 2.1.1 built 4/28/16 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with apologies to the Great Udini:

ok. I did it. I've tested a little bit and it runs (but I haven't tested enough to say it runs *correctly*).

The biggest issue was tracking down some old deprecated libs `httpclientandroid*.jar`.

and adding a `build.gradle`.

I just simply copied the source `dirs/*.javas` over.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to present such updates. I tried to fork/branch off the original but the Android Studio ui for Github fails. It's pretty sparse.

```
https://github.com/NTierSoftware/AccountAuthenticator/tree/master
```

p.s. I just emailed Udi Cohen, the orig author, and notified him. If he objects to me not forking correctly, well perhaps someone can help me.